# CLPFD "OR" condition in domain declaration

Tags: prolog, clpfd

Is there a way to express OR condition in the following problem without introducing an extra predicate `p` (this is Project Euler 1):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

p(B) :-
  B in 0..1000,
( B mod 3 #= 0 ; B mod 5 #= 0 ),
  indomain(B).

euler_001(A) :-
  aggregate_all(sum(B), p(B), A).
```

If I place `;` within same goal:

```
euler_001(A) :-
  B in 0..1000,
( B mod 3 #= 0 ; B mod 5 #= 0 ),
  aggregate_all(sum(B), indomain(B), A).
```

The result is actually:

```
?- euler_001(R).
R = 166833 ;
R = 100500.
```

which intuitively makes sense, as the `;` produces backtracking, so the sum is computed twice, once for numbers divisible by 3, and once for numbers divisible by 5.

Comment: You may use `aggregate_all/4`, using the number (in this case `B`) as the discriminator. That is, in your first sample code use `aggregate_all(sum(B), B, p(B), A)`

Comment: Or better, you can use `#\/` to express the or condition. So instead of  `B mod 3 #= 0 ; B mod 5 #= 0` use `B mod 3 #= 0 #\/ B mod 5 #= 0`

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

euler_001(A) :-
  B in 0..1000,
  B mod 3 #= 0 #\/ B mod 5 #= 0,
  aggregate_all(sum(B), B, A).
```